# Is there a way to create custom menu buttons in electron without node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

When creating custom Title Bar buttons like close, min/max, restore I came across the issue that I may need to use the remote in the renderer.

> Renderer - With nodeIntegration

```
const { remote } = require('electron');

const mainWindow = remote.getCurrentWindow();

document.getElementById('close').addEventListener('click', () => {
  mainWindow.close();
});
```

Obviously this requires node but I want to keep nodeIntegration off and out of the renderer as I heard that was best. Is it possible to create custom buttons for the Title Bar without using nodeIntegration?

If this can't be done without nodeIntegration, what is a safe way?

Comment: Don't you think you are already using node ?

Comment: @MudasarRauf Nope. The above code is the nodeIntegration method for the Renderer process. I'll label that.